# How do I stop formset from deleting values I keep zero

Tags: django, django-forms

So, the default value of some integer fields in a one-to-many relationship model is zero. 
And if I don't edit them nd save the form, the values get deleted.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code that represents what you are describing?

Comment: Welcome to SO - please see how to write a [mcve] so that others stand a chance of helping you.